# How to show menu links in dashboard of Admin LTE

Tags: php, hyperlink, laravel-5, dashboard, adminlte

iam trying to develop a php project with admin LTE, in my dashboard.php I'm adding:

```
<?php include_once('first.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('sidebar.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('content.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('sidebarcontrol.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('script.php'); ?>
```

Know I want to show the sidebar links (left Menu) in dashboard section (right) in the same page.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the PHP framework you use for project

Comment: sandun priyanka  thank for your atention. Iam using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Have you went through this LINK https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel ??